# dired mode single window? (emacs)

Tags: emacs, elisp, file-management, dired

is there a way to have dired operate in a single window so that when I traverse through directories I don't have n number of dired buffers for the intermediate directories? However - if I start another dired buffer in a completely separate directory (from the minibuffer rather than hitting [enter] on a subdirectory in an already open dired instance) I'd like to retain the two separate dired buffers... I guess I'm using ido-dired since I have ido-mode on but I don't know that the solution would be different? Thanks much!

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839313/how-do-i-stop-emacs-dired-mode-from-opening-so-many-buffers/1839493

Comment: Sorry y'all, I did Google for this beforehand, I promise! Didn't realize the answer was everywhere. But thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reduce the `dired-buffer` clutter by hitting <kbd>a</kbd> (`dired-find-alternate-file`) on subdirectories, rather than <kbd>RET</kbd>; that recycles the current dired window.

Answer (score 11):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-single.el

> ```
> ;;; dired-single.el --- Reuse the current dired buffer to visit another directory...
>
> ;;; Commentary:
> ;;
> ;;  This package provides a way to reuse the current dired buffer to visit
> ;;  another directory (rather than creating a new buffer for the new directory).
> ;;  Optionally, it allows the user to specify a name that all such buffers will
> ;;  have, regardless of the directory they point to...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

[**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus) lets you do this optionally, and it lets you toggle it on/off anytime.

See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
(defadvice dired-find-file (around kill-old-buffer activate)
    "When navigate from one dired buffer to another, kill the old one."
    (let ((old-buffer (current-buffer))
          (new-buffer (dired-get-filename))) 
      ad-do-it
      (kill-buffer old-buffer)
      (switch-to-buffer new-buffer)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mostly want to have each dired buffer work with various subdirs that are all under a single hierarchy (e.g. one dired buffer for each of several ongoing projects), you can use the built-in `i` (*dired-maybe-insert-subdir*) and `k` (*dired-do-kill-lines* on the header of an inserted subdir to remove it from the buffer) commands. They will let you edit multiple directories inside a single dired buffer. You might want a small custom command and to remap `RET` if it is too ingrained in your muscle memory though.