# Emacs dired use the same buffer

Tags: emacs, dired

I use the following code in `.emacs`:

```
(require 'dired+)
(toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

So it won't create a buffer for every dir I visit. Then I decided to add some ergonomics:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-<up>") 'dired-up-directory)))
```

So when I click `Ctrl-<up>` it will move to the parent directory. But it opens the parent dir in a new buffer.

How to make it open in the same buffer?

Comment: btw there is a typo, the function is toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir,

Comment: @PuercoPop Where is the typo? `toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir` function exists and works, while your function with p doesn't exist in my Emacs.

Comment: it doesn't exist in mine and it immediately corrects it to the p variant. What version are you running? pretty weird

Comment: @PuercoPop GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)
 of 2012-06-10 on MARVIN. Here is the Help for this function: toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in `dired+.el'.

(toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir FORCE-P)

Toggle whether Dired `find-file' commands use alternate file.
Non-nil prefix arg FORCE-P => Use alternate file iff FORCE-P >= 0.

Comment: **Note/update:** Since at least 2011 the name of the command has been `toggle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir`, with a **`p`** in `diredp`. There is no such command without the `p`. A typo (no `p`) remained for a while, but it was fixed on 2011/07/01.

Comment: i did an edit to the post with to add the `p` to it.  i wasted a good chunk of time with the cut-and-paste of it for a while before reading the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop emacs dired mode from opening so many buffers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839313/how-do-i-stop-emacs-dired-mode-from-opening-so-many-buffers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution can be found [there](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer):

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-<up>")
    (lambda () (interactive) (find-alternate-file "..")))
  ; was dired-up-directory
 ))
```