# Emacs: how to open dired bookmarks in the same window

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks, dired

I managed to make dired work in a single window, when I am navigating through the file system.

Improving ergonomics, I decided to create bookmarks for my most frequent dirs with short names like: 'lwt', 'eve', etc. But every time I open the bookmark, the new dired buffer is created, even if the old one exists.

How to make it open the bookmark in the existing dired buffer?

Answer (score 4):

### Edit:

The original answer was actually a non-answer. I apologise for not having tested it properly. I will leave it here so other potential answerers aren't misled like I was.

I have meanwhile taken a good look at the source code of [`bookmark.el`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/bookmark.el) and the `dired+` modifications don't have any effect on it. By default the [`bookmark-jump`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/bookmark.el#L1015) function uses the `switch-to-buffer` function as its display function. [`bookmark-jump`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/bookmark.el#L1015) however has an optional `display-func` argument, so a possible solution (involving a bit of elisp hacking) would be to create a function that reuses the current dired buffer (based on the `dired+` source code) and invoking `bookmark-jump` with it, and if the concept works, then bind that to a keyboard short-cut.

### Original answer:

The behaviour you are observing is just a side effect of the general *"create a new buffer when navigating"* behaviour of *dired*. This fact makes this question an almost duplicate of [How do I stop emacs dired mode from opening so many buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839313/how-do-i-stop-emacs-dired-mode-from-opening-so-many-buffers).

Of the solutions proposed there and at the [Dired Reuse Directory Buffer](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer) Emacs Wiki page, probably the simplest one is installing the [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) package and toggling directory buffer reuse with:

```
(toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: I already have this line in my .emacs file. It works for everything except for bookmarks opening.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. I am now experimenting with elisp and will try to post the code here, when it's working.

Answer (score 1):

With [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus), at least, `bookmark-jump` (`C-x j j`) to a Dired bookmark does reuse the Dired buffer if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help - that's what I use to open my bookmarks in the same buffer.

```
(defun my-bookmarks-list-same-buffer ()
  "Open *Bookmarks* in current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-bmenu-list)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Bookmark List*"))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-b") 'my-bookmarks-list-same-buffer)
```